# C++ DHCP Host Name Used As Unique Identifier?

Tags: c++, uniqueidentifier, identifier, dhcp

I'm currently looking into some ways to identify different machines using my software, I am working with a old gaming console in which I cannot access the typical unique identifiers most people would use (HWID, etc...).

After looking through the SDK required to compile software on this old gaming console I noticed I can get a users DHCP Host Name, (You can view your DHCP Host Name on a windows machine by entering "hostname.exe" within command prompt)

So my question is, would using the DHCP Host Name as a way to uniquely identify different machines accessing my software be effective in differentiating different users?

Comment: Uniquely within a local network? Or uniquely across the internet (or something else)? Furthermore, shouldn’t even old game consoles have a MAC address if they have a network adapter? That’s usually sufficiently unique, despite being spoof-able.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Across the entire internet, and yes I am also able to get the MAC address, though people can easily spoof that which Is why I was looking into other options.

Comment: Well the DHCP host name can be adjusted even easier than the MAC address. It’s a simple setting, and unlike the MAC address it’s neither supposed to be immutable nor unique. In fact, by default a DHCP server may change your machine’s host name externally.

Comment: @KonradRudolph so there's a possibility that the DHCP host name will change even if the user doesn't manually change it? Yeah, then there's no way I will be able to use this as a unique identifier. I was thinking about using the DHCP host name in combination with the MAC to generate a unique identifier, but if the DHCP host name is constantly changing that won't work :/

Comment: I'm wondering a bit about this "DHCP Host name". What exactly does that mean? Is that a client host name, generated by the DHCP server, or the host name announced by a DHCP client?

Comment: @Power5 I don't think anyone implied it's _constantly changing_, but the point is it _can_ change, and generally can be more easily changed than spoofing a MAC address. You also have the problem that you may see many instances of `MyPC`, `HomePC` or `MumsPC`.